# get current id of widget on python / kivy

Tags: python, kivy, python-2.x

i'm making a sort of android lock thing on kivy, and to draw the line, I need to get the id of the widget the mouse is on, so I assing an id to each one like this in the .kv file:

```
ClickableImage:
    id: one
    source: 'button.png'
    etc.
```

and I know I can get all the ids (I have 9, of course), with the

```
self.parent.ids.id
```

or

```
self.parent.ids['id']
```

but is there a way to get the ID the mouse is in? or the one I click? I have a hoverable class so it detects when it enters in a Widget, but I don't really know how to get its position, or change its source.
Is there any:

```
self.parten.ids.current
```

or something like that?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collide_widget`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_widget) or [`collide_point`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) and in the widget set a method that will change a variable in the `parent`, let's say `selected_widget` to the current widget's like this:

```
if self.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
    self.parent.selected_widget = self  # or its id
```

Then you can do with it anything. Maybe it'd be even better to put your logic into the widget itself and handle collision directly there. Obviously you'll need to bind a method you create with that `if` block above to an event such as `on_release` or `on_press` so run the method, otherwise it won't do a thing.

You can also get a hoverable behavior from [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4734) PR or even from [this](https://gist.github.com/opqopq/15c707dc4cffc2b6455f) snippet.

**Edit:**

> Please note that the id will not be available in the widget instance

Which means `self.ids.my_id.id == None` and therefore to actually get `id` you need to do this:

```
def find(self, parent, widget):
    for id, obj in parent.ids.items():
        if obj == widget:
            print id
            return id
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea but, I remember there is a way to get variables from the main class (App), I declared it there, and then there was a method something like ".get_running_App" or a thing like that.. (I can't find that either, I don't think the Documentation is very clear I think). Any chance you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: `self.app = App.get_running_app()` most likely in `__init__` method and then you can get anything from `App` class basically via `self.app.<thing>`

Comment: The only thing I need left, is to get the id of the current id the mouse is on, because when I print Self, or self.id, I only get <__main__.ClickableImage object at 0x7fa671a713d0>, or None, how can I get the id of the current Widget I'm on? So I can transfer it to a variable in App and work with it